# Require Function Broken Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethers.js

In the code below, I try to create a check that the allowance of the contract to spend the sender's tokens is greater than the required amount. When I emit the Succeeded event and log it in the console, it logs as true. However, the code never can get past the require event and always logs "Insufficient USDC allowance" even though they are both using the same condition.

```
emit Succeeded(IERC20(USDCAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this))>=requiredAmount);
require(IERC20(USDCAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this))>=requiredAmount, "Insufficient USDC allowance");
```

This is extremely mind boggling and any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
This contract is being deployed on the Polygon Mumbai Testnet. Full contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

//Insurance smart contract
contract InsuranceAgreement {
    
    //ADDRESSES
    //master wallet who deployed smart contract (me)
    address public master=0xbCCc6A9926455a43EB72700fA99BD4A98ba6A087;  //Testing

    //address public master = 0x6781d837FD7Bda919c5d8ab3e71d6e5833346450; //Testnet
    address USDCAddress = 0xE097d6B3100777DC31B34dC2c58fB524C2e76921; //Testnet

    //buyer public address
    address public buyerAddr;
    //seller public address
    address public sellerAddr;
    
    //INITIAL TERMS OF CONTRACT
    //premium required
    uint256 premiumRequired;
    //payout required
    uint256 payoutRequired;
    //timeline of insurance agreement (in seconds)
    uint256 duration;

    //CASH
    //premium 
    uint256 premium;
    //payout 
    uint256 payout;

    //TIMES
    //contract finalized time in seconds
    uint256 finalizedTime;
    //contract initailization time
    uint256 initializedTime;
    //last time withdrew premium
    uint256 lastWithdrewPremium;


    //CANCELLATION 
    //bool if buyer wants to cancel
    bool buyerCancel;
    //bool if seller wants to cancel
    bool sellerCancel;


    //contract initialized 
    constructor(address _sellerAddr, uint256 _duration, uint256 _premiumRequired, uint256 _payoutRequired) {
        //avoid invalid terms
        require(_premiumRequired>0, "Premium must be greater than 0");
        require(_payoutRequired>0, "Payout must be greater than 0");
        require(_duration>0, "Duration must be greater than 0");
        //initialize addresses
        buyerAddr = msg.sender;
        sellerAddr = _sellerAddr;
        //initialize contract terms
        duration = _duration;
        premiumRequired = _premiumRequired;
        payoutRequired = _payoutRequired;
        
    }
    
    //Events for logging
    event TimeStamp(uint256 value);
    event NumTokens(uint256 value);
    event Address(address value);
    event Succeeded(bool value);

    //only allow master wallet to access function
    modifier onlyMaster() {
        require(msg.sender == master, "You are not the master");
        _;
    }
    //only allow seller to access function
    modifier requireSeller(){
        require(msg.sender==sellerAddr, "You are not the seller");
        _;
    }
    //only allow buyer to access function
    modifier requireBuyer(){
        require(msg.sender==buyerAddr, "You are not the buyer");
        _;
    }
    modifier requireFinalizationPeriodNotExpired(){
        require(block.timestamp-initializedTime<=60*60*24*2, "Finalization period already expired");
        _;
    }
    modifier requireAgreementNotOver(){
        require(block.timestamp-finalizedTime<duration, "Agreement duration already over");
        _;
    }
    //ensure that agreement is finalized
    modifier requireFinalized(){
        require(finalizedTime>0, "Agreement not yet finalized");
        _;
    }

       
       

    //deposit premium to initialize contract
    function depositPremium() external requireBuyer {
        
         //deposit premium to create "pending" contract
         uint256 allowance = IERC20(USDCAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
         emit NumTokens(allowance); 
       require(allowance>=premiumRequired, "Insufficient USDC allowance");
        /*require(IERC20(USDCAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), premiumRequired), "Failed to transfer USDC premium");
        //Require premium not locked in
        require(premium ==0, "Premium already locked in");
         //initialize deposit -- wait for payout to be locked in
        premium+=premiumRequired;
        //set contract initialization time
        initializedTime=block.timestamp; */
    }

    //deposit payout to finalize contract
    function depositPayout() external requireFinalizationPeriodNotExpired requireSeller {
        //make sure payout valid
        require(premium==premiumRequired,"Premium not yet deposited");
        require(IERC20(USDCAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= payoutRequired, "Insufficient USDC allowance");
        require(IERC20(USDCAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), payoutRequired), "Failed to transfer USDC payout");
        require(payout==0,"Payout already locked in");
        //finalize agreement and lock in payout
        payout+=payoutRequired;
        finalizedTime=block.timestamp;
        lastWithdrewPremium=block.timestamp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the Succeeded event?

Comment: Yep, here ```event Succeeded(bool value);```.

Comment: Could you possibly edit the post to include the full code for the contract? Or at least the function?

Comment: And the address of the contract you are wrapping in an IERC20?

Comment: So I'm pretty sure the issue here lies in the USDC contract (or at least the usage of that specific ERC20 implementation) as I was not able to recreate the issue with a standard openzeppelin ERC20 token and the source code for the insurance contract in remix. Could you possibly post the code for the USDC contract?

Comment: I don't have code for the USDC contract actually, but I tried using a different ERC20 contract as well and it gave me the same problem. Which one did you use? Also can I see your implementation for calling "approve" and the transfer?

Comment: I actually found a fix. Apparently, the deposit premium function didn't wait long enough after the approve function had been called, but with the wait, it was actually able to work properly. Thank you so much for all your help!